# How to redirect https://www to https:// in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to redirect https://www to https:// in nginx but never succeed. Below is my configuration file :

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80; # 
server_name example.com www.example.com;
return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name example.com;
index index.php;

root /home/username/sites/example.com/public;

ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem";
ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem";

}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a server block for www.example.com that handles HTTPS:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem";
}
```

Don't forget the certificate for it.